# How much HTML5 android browser supports?

Tags: android, html, webkit

How much HTML5 android 2.2 's browser supports?

Is there any place/doc where I can find that what all HTML5 tags are supported by android 2.2 browser.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://html5test.com/

This site shows how much of the HTML5 your current browser supports.

It's only a matter of browsing it from android :)

Answer (score 5):

According to the platform overview, the following features of HTML5 are supported:

- Database API support, for client-side databases using SQL.
- Application cache support, for offline applications.
- Geolocation API support, to provide location information about the device.
- tag support in fullscreen mode.